# sql injection on limit clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

Is there any possibility to exploit a sql injection in the following query?

```
mysql_query("SELECT `one`, `two`, `three` FROM test LIMIT ".$vulnerablepost.",2;") or die(mysql_error());
```

What are possible types of possible queries? Is it possible de perform a SELECT OUTFILE?
Thanks

Comment: Yes it is. Since the input can be manipulated or adjusted to inject wrong SQL

Comment: Even if someone gives you a hack, the better bet is to just use prepared statements.  Don't take any chances.

Comment: Can you give me an example code please? Because i didn't manage to do it..

Comment: Instead of looking for an exploit and lazy excuse not to fix it, why not just apply a typecast?

Comment: I don't use raw php anymore, of course I use poo now, it's an old project I done in 2010 (just a school blog) which is online right now, and they asked me if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Since the input can be manipulated or adjusted to inject wrong SQL. What if your input value looks like

```
$vulnerablepost = "20;delete from student_table;select 1";
```

You will ended up in a SQL query like below which is syntactically correct but will put you in trouble

```
SELECT `one`, `two`, `three` FROM test LIMIT 20;delete from student_table;select 1,2;
```

Comment: But it wouldn't be possible to exploit it if multiple queries are disabled? I guess it's the default case. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Xyt, don't just go by my given example. There could others as well moreover why take a chance with your data? you want that coming really? simple practice: if there is user input coming to  your query use parameterized query to avoid SI

Comment: I explained before that's an old project, I'm don't have enough time to work with some old raw code, so if there isn't any possibility, it can be left like that..

Comment: @Xyt: you can get the following answers: "It is possible". Then you have to fix it. "It is possible + an example". Then you have to fix it. No answer. Then you have to fix it (because you cannot be sure). The answer "No, there isn't any possibility". Then you have to fix it because you cannot trust the answer, because it can be that the answer is wrong (maybe because the answerer just couldn't think of an example, or maybe because he could think of an example and knows your site). Either way, you have to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, and you shouldn't be using that. Use PDO or Mysqli.
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

So unless you are using an extremely old version of PHP you should not use that funciton.  You can even check the documentation for that page as well.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
Warning
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
mysqli_query()
PDO::query()
```